# How to get network traffic (i.e. network logs) of an particular application in andrioid?

Tags: android, adb, appium

I need to get the network logs for an application.

Is there any ADB     shell command available to get the network logs ?

Comment: You can do it with fiddler by connecting device to your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Try Facebook Stetho
https://facebook.github.io/stetho/

It is very useful tool to inspect network, databases etc